# Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql

```
select max(postal_code) from address
where max(postal_code) 
IN (select Min(postal_code) from address
group by district
having  min(postal_code) <> "" and district <> "" );
```

can anyone tell me why i got this error?

Comment: `select max(postal_code) m  from address having m ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is in below line. You can't use a group function like that in `WHERE` clause except in `HAVING` clause

```
where max(postal_code)
```

You can try modifying your query like below

```
select max_postalcode 
from 
(
select max(postal_code) as max_postalcode,
Min(postal_code) as min_postal_code 
from address
where district is not null
group by district
having  min(postal_code) is not null
) xxx 
where max_postalcode = min_postal_code;
```